# c# : How to call generic method with paramerters with in a c# method?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, generics, ado.net

My approximate data table structure which i will get from my sqlserver stored proc call. I am using .netframework 3.5 and i want to convert this datatable to json output using ado.net. i have stuck at **GetCountryList(FK,TypeName)**. Kindly help me to acheive the below json output. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
Type        ID   Name          FK

Continent    1  America         0
Continent    2  Asia            0  
Continent    3  Africa          0
Country      11 USA             1
Country      12 China           2
Country      13 India           2
Country      14 Kenya           3
```

**DataEntity**

```
public class UserData
{
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public string ID  { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string FK {get; set;}
}
```

**Service Method**

```
 public static UserData GetUserData() {

   JavaScriptSerializer jSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer ();

    DataTable dtUserData = DataAccess.getUserDataTable();

   if(dtUserData !=null && dtUserData.Rows.Count>0)
   {
      List<DataRow> list = dtMasterData.AsEnumerable().ToList();

      List<UserData> lstContinent = new List<UserData>();
      List<UserData> lstCountry = new List<UserData>();

        foreach(DataRow dr in list)
          {
              var objUserData = new UserData();
              objUserData.ID = dr["ID"].ToString();
              objUserData.Type = dr["Type"].ToString();
              objUserData.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
              objUserData.FK = dr["FK"].ToString();  

              if(objUserData.Type.ToString().ToLower=="continent")
               {
                  lstContinent.Add(objUserData);
               }

              if(objUserData.Type.ToString().ToLower=="country")
               {
                  if(dr["FK"] !=null)
                  {
                    var ForgnKey = dr["FK"].ToString();
                    var TypeName = dr["Type"].ToString();
                    var CountriesList = GetCountryList(FK,TypeName)  //how do i call a generic method to filter out the country list as per passing Continent FK?
                    lstCountry.AddRange(CountriesList);

                 }

                    lstCountry.Add(objUserData);
               }

    private static List<T>  GetCountryList (lstCountry,ForgnKey,TypeName) //Not sure with the syntax
    {
          var CountriesList = lstCountry.Where(p=>p.FK==ForgnKey).ToList();

    }

  }
            return jSerializer.Serialize(objUserData);
```

}

**Expected JSON Output :**

```
"data": {
    "Contnient":
        [
            { "Id": "1", "Type": "Contient", "Name" :"America","FK":"1" },
            { "Id": "2", "Type": "Contient", "Name" :"Asia",   "FK":"2" },
            { "Id": "3", "Type": "Contient", "Name" :"Africa",   "FK":"2" },
            { "Id": "4", "Type": "Contient", "Name" :"Asia",   "FK":"2" }
        ],

    "America":
        {
            "Country":
            [
              { "Id": "11", "Type": "Country","Name":"India","FK":"1" }

            ]
        },
    "Asia:
      {
        "Country":
               [ { "Id": "12", "Type": "Country","Name":"China","FK":"2" },
                 { "Id": "13", "Type": "Country","Name":"India","FK":"2" }
               ]
       }
     "Africa":
       {
        "Country":
               [ { "Id": "14", "Type": "Country","Name":"Kenya","FK":"3" }
               ]

  }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `Call generic method with parameters`?

Comment: i have updated my question with the generic method implementation. But i am not sure, how to call the generic method in my code. The reason for this generic method is, to get the list of countries for each continent. you can refer my expectation at the json output.

Comment: @EricJ. I have updated the expected JSON output.

Comment: what is the reason for negative vote?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the generic function be defined as:

```
private static List<T> GetCountryList<T>(lstCountry,ForgnKey,TypeName)
{
      return lstCountry.Where(p=>p.FK==ForgnKey).ToList();
}
```

Then called as:

```
var CountriesList = GetCountryList<UserData>(lstCountry,FK,TypeName);
```